Navigate to a setup page from a custom notification
Via my Apex controller in the handleResult() callback for a Metadata deployment, I'm sending a custom notification to the user that scheduled the deployment.
public static void notifyUsers(Set<String> recipientsIds, String targetId, String notifTitle, String notifBody) {

        // Get the Id for our custom notification type
        CustomNotificationType notificationType = 
            [SELECT Id, DeveloperName 
             FROM CustomNotificationType 
             WHERE DeveloperName='Deployment_Notification_for_DC_Alerts'];
        
        // Create a new custom notification
        Messaging.CustomNotification notification = new Messaging.CustomNotification();

        // Set the contents for the notification
        notification.setTitle(notifTitle);
        notification.setBody(notifBody);

        // Set the notification type and target
        notification.setNotificationTypeId(notificationType.Id);

        //TODO: Doesn't work to navigate to a setup page, gives an apex error. Minimum of a targetId is required, but clicking it takes to a 'page not found'
        notification.setTargetId(targetId);

        //String baseUrl = System.Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();
        //PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(baseUrl + '/lightning/setup/DeployStatus/page?address=%2Fchangemgmt%2FmonitorDeploymentsDetails.apexp%3FasyncId%3D' + targetId + '%26retURL%3D%252Fchangemgmt%252FmonitorDeployment.apexp');
        //System.debug('pageRef.getUrl(): ' + String.valueOf(pageRef.getUrl()));
        //notification.setTargetPageRef(String.valueOf(pageRef.getUrl()));
        
        // Actually send the notification
        try {
            notification.send(recipientsIds);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Problem sending notification: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

This sort of works, in that the notification is sent but...
When I set the targetId to the deployment Id and the notification is clicked, Salesforce takes me to a 'page not found'.
When I try to set the target to the direct deployment status page using the setTargetPageRef() method. I pass it a page reference but I get the error "common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Invalid parameter value for: targetPageRef", even though the generated URL is correct and takes me to the right page in the browser.
Am I missing something here, or is this just not possible to do?
EDIT: I found these related posts..
A click on a bell icon notification in Communities (now called Digital Experiences) doesn't navigate
This does work and still experience the JS error in the browser console but it does work. Do we foresee this causing any issues longer term?

A related post fixes this issue in that the functionality works:
A click on a bell icon notification in Communities (now called Digital Experiences) doesn't navigate
This does seem to generate a JS error in the browser console, but is probably good enough to do what I need.
